# How to use an if statement in a string array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, random, srand

The following code is supposed to randomly pick a string from the array and then say "Yay!" if Happy has been chosen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));
    string textArray[4] = { "Happy", "Sad", "Mad", "Overjoyed." };
    int RandIndex = rand() % 4;
    cout << textArray[RandIndex] << endl;
    //if (textArray == "Happy") old
    if (RandIndex == 0) //new
    {
        cout << "Yay!" << endl;
    }
    cin.get();
}
```

My problem is that the operand types are incompatible with strings and chars. What would be the best solution to this problem?

EDIT: All I needed to do was replace "if (textArray == "Happy")" with "if (RandIndex == 0)"

Comment: You need to compare an element of textArray, not the array itself. You forgot the `[RandIndex]`. And you could (in that example) also just test if RandIndex == 0.

Comment: What do you mean I forgot the [RandIndex]?

Comment: I tested if RanIndex == 0 and got what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Why did you print the right then then test the wrong thing? Weird...

Comment: I couldn't compile my original code in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

For example like

```
if ( textArray[RandIndex] == "Happy" ) 
{
    cout << "Yay!" << endl;
}
```

or like

```
if ( RandIndex == 0 ) 
{
    cout << "Yay!" << endl;
}
```

Also it would be better to write at least like

```
string textArray[] = { "Happy", "Sad", "Mad", "Overjoyed." };
const size_t N = sizeof( textArray ) / sizeof( *textArray );

size_t randIndex = rand() % N;
```